# i want to add onchange event to my dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

The problem is that I have a form, inside this form I have dropdownlist which contain name of a student which comes from a database and I want to submit form every time I select any value from this dropdownlist. When I try this code:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("StudentId", "--Select Students--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

An error appears to me:

> StudentId is a ViewBag containing List of Students come from
>   database in controller action

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("StudentId", null, "--Select Students--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })` assuming `StudentId` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: Yes Worked Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Comment: thank you but i only need anther attribute when i add null i work greatly as @Stephen Muecke  say